# kubernetes ingress-nginx with kustomize

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, nginx-ingress

I am trying to use `ingress-nginx` from this [URL](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v1.2.0/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml) with ***kustomize***

The working example are in this gist, is pretty simple, no customizations https://gist.github.com/skhaz/7d8fdb03aee624d651c90156021f6ce8

I am using this YAML https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v1.2.0/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml

However, when I run `make create`, which basically runs `kubectl create --kustomize .`

I get the error

```
service/ingress-nginx-controller created
service/ingress-nginx-controller-admission created
deployment.apps/ingress-nginx-controller created
job.batch/ingress-nginx-admission-create created
job.batch/ingress-nginx-admission-patch created
ingressclass.networking.k8s.io/nginx created
Error from server (AlreadyExists): error when creating ".": namespaces "ingress-nginx" already exists
Error from server (AlreadyExists): error when creating ".": serviceaccounts "ingress-nginx" already exists
Error from server (AlreadyExists): error when creating ".": serviceaccounts "ingress-nginx-admission" already exists
Error from server (AlreadyExists): error when creating ".": roles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "ingress-nginx" already exists
Error from server (AlreadyExists): error when creating ".": roles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "ingress-nginx-admission" already exists
Error from server (AlreadyExists): error when creating ".": clusterroles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "ingress-nginx" already exists
Error from server (AlreadyExists): error when creating ".": clusterroles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "ingress-nginx-admission" already exists
Error from server (AlreadyExists): error when creating ".": rolebindings.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "ingress-nginx" already exists
Error from server (AlreadyExists): error when creating ".": rolebindings.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "ingress-nginx-admission" already exists
Error from server (AlreadyExists): error when creating ".": clusterrolebindings.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "ingress-nginx" already exists
Error from server (AlreadyExists): error when creating ".": clusterrolebindings.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "ingress-nginx-admission" already exists
Error from server (AlreadyExists): error when creating ".": configmaps "ingress-nginx-controller" already exists
Error from server (AlreadyExists): error when creating ".": validatingwebhookconfigurations.admissionregistration.k8s.io "ingress-nginx-admission" already exists
```

What I am doing wrong?

`kubectl apply` works, but I want to customize with **kustomize**

Answer (score 1):

The error was on `kubectl create`, should be `kubectl apply`